# Where should I store localized server-side files and how should I look them up when using ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I need to store some server-side files (email templates) in an ASP.NET application. The files will be localized. How should I store and look up these files, including a fall-back method similar to the resx approach?

Comment: Why not store them as resources as well

Comment: I want to store them in files - they will get pretty big and unwieldy for the resx editor I believe. But when I add a file resource to a resx file, it simply generates a text file (without any locale data in the name) in the same directory. Localizing it won't be as easy as with strings. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In the end I'm kind of delaying this functionality until we start with translation. I'm just storing the file paths in normal resource strings and create separate text files that I can name whatever I want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate folder for each template, then create a file for each localization adding the culture code to its extension. So for the "welcome" email template, you will have something like this.

```
EmailTemplates\
EmailTemplates\Welcome\
EmailTemplates\Welcome\welcome.txt
EmailTemplates\Welcome\welcome.jp-JP.txt
EmailTemplates\Welcome\welcome.th-TH.txt
```

Use File.Exists(..) to check if the file exists and then fallback to the default English template.

You can get the current culture code by using the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name property.
For more info on culture codes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I hope this puts you on the right track.